# How to check permission for posting on group facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I use FQL to retrieve the group list:

```
SELECT gid, name, privacy FROM group WHERE gid IN (SELECT gid FROM group_member WHERE uid=me())
```

When i tried post message in group wall (with the privacy is OPEN) but failed.

And in *Group settings*, there is an option *Posting permissions*.

http://i.imgbox.com/adgtjrOK.jpg

So how do I get the *Posting permissions* before posting message.

Please help me!

Comment: Are You one of the admin(s) of the group You trying to post?
because the group You trying to post to its wall has a rule that **only admin(s) can/make post** in the group while other regular members can't

Comment: Im not admin of the group. How do get status `can_post`?

Comment: You can't, unless the group admin make possible for members to post

Comment: `$foreach($list as $group){
$params = array(
"message"=>"Message"
);
$facebook->api("/GROUP_ID/feed","POST",$param);
}`
If permission postting not allowed by admin, things will not be able to continue. Please help me!

Comment: Your code should work! try another group

Comment: I did post on wall, everything is fine. Thanks for answering me!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question but I was facing the same issue and found the solution.
FQL has a table named `profile` that is returning `can_post`. 
A `profile` can be a `group`, `page`, `user`, `application` or `event` see [FQL Facebook Profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/profile/)

To know if a user can post in a group:

```
SELECT id, can_post FROM profile WHERE id = <group_id>

{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": <group_id>, 
      "can_post": false
    }
  ]
}
```

You can use the same for any type of profile.

Comment: Thanks, here is the solution for me!